# Google colab : How can i mount two google drive accounts?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I have two google accounts each one contains part of my data and i can,t include the data into one drive because of the size limit. So, I want to know if there is a way to mount the two drive accounts into colab.

Comment: Please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728127/mount-multiple-drives-in-google-colab

Answer (score 5):

You can use `auth.authenticate_user()` then access your second drive through pydrive API. Then you can move files from your second drive to the first one (mounted with `drive.mount()`).

```
from google.colab import auth

auth.authenticate_user()
```