# Mount Multiple Google Drive Account with Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am trying to connect and Mount multiple Google Drive account with Google Colab. So, `qDiffusion Application` load file from both Google Drive account and show in the `client app`

*Github Repo for reference :* https://github.com/arenasys/qDiffusion

**Original Code ([Notebook URL](https://colab.research.google.com/github/arenasys/qDiffusion/blob/master/remote_colab.ipynb)):**

```
%cd /content
import IPython.display
import os
import sys

if not os.path.exists("/content/sd-inference-server"):
    !git clone https://github.com/arenasys/sd-inference-server.git

%cd /content/sd-inference-server
model_folder = "/content/sd-inference-server/models"
try:
    # decline the popup to use the local folder ^
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
    model_folder = "/content/drive/My Drive/qDiffusion/models"
    if not os.path.exists(model_folder):
        !mkdir '/content/drive/My Drive/qDiffusion' -p
        !cp -r 'models/' '/content/drive/My Drive/qDiffusion/'
except Exception as e:
    pass

if not os.path.exists("venv"):
    !curl -OJL https://huggingface.co/datasets/arenasys/qDiffusion/resolve/main/cached_venv5.tar
    !tar xf cached_venv5.tar; mv cached_venv5 venv; rm cached_venv5.tar
    !rm /content/sd-inference-server/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pathlib.py
    !pip install timm==0.6.13
    !pip install tomesd==0.1.3
    !pip install torchmetrics
    !pip uninstall -y tensorflow

    !wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/367274644/libgoogle-perftools-dev_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
    !wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/google-perftools/2.5-2.2ubuntu3/+build/14795286/+files/google-perftools_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_all.deb
    !wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/google-perftools/2.5-2.2ubuntu3/+build/14795286/+files/libtcmalloc-minimal4_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
    !wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/google-perftools/2.5-2.2ubuntu3/+build/14795286/+files/libgoogle-perftools4_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
    !apt install -qq libunwind8-dev
    !dpkg -i *.deb
    %env LD_PRELOAD=libtcmalloc.so

    IPython.display.clear_output()

if not sys.path[0] == "/content/sd-inference-server/":
    sys.path.insert(0, "/content/sd-inference-server/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages")
    sys.path.insert(0, "/content/sd-inference-server/")

from pycloudflared import try_cloudflare
tunnel_url = try_cloudflare(port=28888, verbose=False)
print("ENDPOINT:", tunnel_url.tunnel.replace("https", "wss"))

!python remote.py "$model_folder"

try_cloudflare.terminate(28888)
```

**Multiple Mount Code ([Solution from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57394402/20776947)) :**

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
!mkdir -p /drive2
!google-drive-ocamlfuse /drive2
```

**After Merging, i am trying Like :**

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Define a function to connect and mount Google Drive
def mount_drive():
    creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    import getpass
    vcode = getpass.getpass()
    !google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} -code={vcode}

# Define a function to mount a specific Google Drive account
def mount_google_drive(account_name, drive_path):
    # Create a folder to mount the drive
    mount_folder = f"/drive_{account_name}"
    !mkdir -p {mount_folder}
    # Mount the drive
    !google-drive-ocamlfuse {mount_folder}
    # Move the contents to the desired drive path
    !mv {mount_folder}/* {drive_path}
    # Remove the empty folder
    !rm -rf {mount_folder}

# Example usage:
mount_drive()

# Mount and specify the accounts and paths
accounts = [
    {"name": "account1", "drive_path": "/content/drive/My Drive/qDiffusion/models"},
    {"name": "account2", "drive_path": "/content/drive/My Drive/other_drive"}
]

for account in accounts:
    print(f"Mounting {account['name']}...")
    mount_google_drive(account["name"], account["drive_path"])
    print(f"{account['name']} mounted at {account['drive_path']}")

%cd /content
import IPython.display
import os
import sys

if not os.path.exists("/content/sd-inference-server"):
    !git clone https://github.com/arenasys/sd-inference-server.git

%cd /content/sd-inference-server
model_folder = "/content/sd-inference-server/models"
try:
    # decline the popup to use the local folder ^
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
    model_folder = "/content/drive/My Drive/qDiffusion/models"
    if not os.path.exists(model_folder):
        !mkdir '/content/drive/My Drive/qDiffusion' -p
        !cp -r 'models/' '/content/drive/My Drive/qDiffusion/'
except Exception as e:
    pass

if not os.path.exists("venv"):
    !curl -OJL https://huggingface.co/datasets/arenasys/qDiffusion/resolve/main/cached_venv5.tar
    !tar xf cached_venv5.tar; mv cached_venv5 venv; rm cached_venv5.tar
    !rm /content/sd-inference-server/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pathlib.py
    !pip install timm==0.6.13
    !pip install tomesd==0.1.3
    !pip install torchmetrics
    !pip uninstall -y tensorflow

    !wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/367274644/libgoogle-perftools-dev_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
    !wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/google-perftools/2.5-2.2ubuntu3/+build/14795286/+files/google-perftools_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_all.deb
    !wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/google-perftools/2.5-2.2ubuntu3/+build/14795286/+files/libtcmalloc-minimal4_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
    !wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/google-perftools/2.5-2.2ubuntu3/+build/14795286/+files/libgoogle-perftools4_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
    !apt install -qq libunwind8-dev
    !dpkg -i *.deb
    %env LD_PRELOAD=libtcmalloc.so

    IPython.display.clear_output()

if not sys.path[0] == "/content/sd-inference-server/":
    sys.path.insert(0, "/content/sd-inference-server/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages")
    sys.path.insert(0, "/content/sd-inference-server/")

from pycloudflared import try_cloudflare
tunnel_url = try_cloudflare(port=28888, verbose=False)
print("ENDPOINT:", tunnel_url.tunnel.replace("https", "wss"))

!python remote.py "$model_folder"

try_cloudflare.terminate(28888)
```

It not working as expected. No popup to connect different Google Drive account and No EndPoint TryCloudflare Public URL.